# JSTL forEach indexing issue

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a nested jstl forEach loop and for some reason whenever the code gets to the inner most loop the indexing restarts. As a result the buttons are generated with duplicate id's when I try to use the index as part of the id. Shouldn't the indexing continues or am I looking at this incorrectly? Here is a code snippet.

```
    <c:forEach items="${groups}" var="group" varStatus="groupstatus">

        <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item" varStatus="itemstatus">

            <c:forEach items="${form.properties}" var="property" varStatus="status">

                   <button id="btn-${status-index}">title here</button>

            </c:forEach>

        </c:forEach>

    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Show us the code for displaying your buttons / IDs. Which index are you using at this point? `groupstatus`? `itemstatus`? `status`?

Comment: at that point i would be using status to construct the id's I updated the code above to show the buttons.

Comment: Is this meant to be `${status.index}` (notice the `.`)?

Comment: `status` is going to be local to the inner loop. It will reset for each iteration of `${items}`. If you are looking for a globally unique ID at that level maybe you want something like `btn-${groupstatus.index}-${itemstatus.index}-${status.index}`.

Comment: Thank you @BeauGrantham, yes that should have been status.index. I thought it may have been local but I was not sure how exactly the indexing worked.

Comment: Are you aware of any tricks that will make the indexing on the inner most loop continue?

Comment: Introducing a variable `<c:set var="myCounter" value="1" />` outside the loop scope and then increasing it each iteration manually could accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`status` is going to be local to the inner loop. It will reset for each iteration of `${items}`.

If you are looking for a globally unique ID at that level maybe you want something like `btn-${groupstatus.index}-${itemstatus.index}-${status.index}`.